# PHP equivalent of JavaScript's substring()

Tags: php

JavaScript has two handy substring functions: `substring(from,to)` and `substr(start,length)`.

This means I can decide "when I get my substring starting from position X, do I want to specify what string position to end on or how many characters long the substring is?"

(One nice usage of the `from, to` version is to use `search()` to determine both positions.)

PHP's `substr()` lets you specify the length of the substring. Is there a built-in string function to let you specify the character position to end on?

Comment: I think you mean that PHP's `substr()` does the latter... it takes the length as a parameter.

Comment: @Felix Kling - yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this question is more about logic.  You can accomplish both with the `substr()` function.

For instance. for the First `substring(from, to)`:

```
$string = 'Foo Bar!';
$from   = 2;
$to     = 5;
$final_string = substr($string, $from, $to - $from);
```

And the second `substr(start,length)`:

```
$string = 'Foo Bar!';
$start  = 2;
$length = 5;
$final_string = substr($string, $start, $length);
```

Comment: Yeah, ok, that makes sense. I just wondered if I was missing something in the jungle of PHP string functions. :)

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to Nick's answer, you can always write the substring function yourself:

```
function substring($string, $from, $to){
    return substr($string, $from, $to - $from);
}
```

I also have a PHP file with some JavaScript like function as the strtruncate() function and include them to the PHP script I need them for.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you need a PHP port of JavaScript's "substring" method here's a reliable port I had to write time ago:

```
/**
 * PHP port of JavaScript's "substring" function
 * Author: Tubal Martin http://blog.margenn.com
 * Tests: http://margenn.com/tubal/substring/
 *
 * @param string $str
 * @param int    $from index
 * @param int    $to index (optional)
 */
private function substring($str, $from = 0, $to = FALSE)
{
    if ($to !== FALSE) {
        if ($from == $to || ($from <= 0 && $to < 0)) {
            return '';
        }

        if ($from > $to) {
            $from_copy = $from;
            $from = $to;
            $to = $from_copy;
        }
    }

    if ($from < 0) {
        $from = 0;
    }

    $substring = $to === FALSE ? substr($str, $from) : substr($str, $from, $to - $from);
    return ($substring === FALSE) ? '' : $substring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`substr(string, start, length)` is a standard usage of the function [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Sorry, my "former" and "latter" stuff was confusing. I was asking about how to specify the end position.