# Get a number of characters from a string using PHP

Tags: php, string, function

I want to grab only the first 80 characters from a string, `$string`, using PHP.

Is there a function for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pull first 100 characters of a string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317336/how-do-you-pull-first-100-characters-of-a-string-in-php) and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result = substr($string, 0, 80);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
substr($string, 0, 80);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:
[PHP equivilent of Javascript's substring()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579481/php-equivilent-of-javascripts-substring)

The text below was written by Nick Shepherd on the topic above.

```
$string = 'Foo Bar!';
$from   = 2;
$to     = 5;
$final_string = substr($string, $from, $to - $from);
```

or

```
$string = 'Foo Bar!';
$start  = 2;
$length = 5;
$final_string = substr($string, $start, $length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the *[substr](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)* function like,

```
 $result = substr($string, 0, 80);
```